# OneNote equations - Bigger integrals and other hidden features

Tags: microsoft-onenote, equation-editor

I can't find any useful official documentation for the many features (and bugs) of the OneNote equation editor invoked with Alt+= or with insert -> Math.

One thing I discovered "by accident" today is how to make integrals (and sums and other such symbols) larger:

normal input:

```
\int_1^2[space](a/b)/(c/d)[space]dx
```

Result:

[image: integer is fixed-size]

It turns out that if I add "130" after `\int`, like so:

```
\int130_1^2[space](a/b)/(c/d)[space]dx
```

Result:

[image: Integer grows to fit whole expression inside it]

And finally, through experimentation, if I use 140 instead of 130 it puts the limits above and below the integral symbol, rather than as subscript and superscript:

[image]

**My question is:** What do 130 and 140 mean? What other options are there? Where do they come from?

Comment: Worth noting in case this makes it into Google results: while writing this question I found this great unofficial reference/tutorial: https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~khitron/Equation%20Editor.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered enough info via experimentation to answer my own question.

The number immediately following the integral (before the limits) - I call it the attribute - seems to be treated as a bit field.

The 3 least significant bits (values 0 to 7) seem to control whether the limits go above/below the integral or as subscript/superscript:

Values 1 make the limits go above and below the integral symbol.

Values 0, 2, 3 and 7 make the limits appear as subscript and superscript. This is also the default behavior.

Values 4 and 6 make above/below in OneNote for Windows 10 and OneNote 2016, but on the web version of OneNote they make sub/supertext.

Value 5 makes above/below on the web, but not in the apps.

The bit with significance of 128 enables the vertical auto-sizing that I was talking about. It only affects rendering in the apps, not in the web version.

All other bits don't seem to affect anything that I could see. Only 8 bits are saved, meaning 128 is the most significant bit, and the largest argument that could be used hypothetically is 255.

**Conclusions:**

If you want the limits to go above and below the integral symbol, use \int1_a^b.

If you want the integral to resize automatically to match the contents, use \int128_a^b. The limits _a and ^b are optional.

If you want both, use \int129_a^b.

Comment: I still need to check how this affects other big operators like \sum, \prod and the like, but I'm not sure if I will.